# How to set grub to load Linux automatically?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I tried installing arch Linux but got a problem when loading it the grub menu is opened now to run the distro I need to run the following commands: 
`set root=(hd0,gpt9)`

`Linux /boot/vmlinux.. root=/dev/sda9`

`Initrd /boot/init....img`

`Boot`

After that arch Linux is loaded 
But I have to do it everytime I boot it is there any way to automatically load it without running these commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install `os-prober` in the main distro, arch-linux will be detected automatically and added to `grub.cfg` after `update-grub`.

Or write the configuration to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux Custom" {
set root=(hd0,gpt9)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda9
initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
```

Then run `update-grub`